# Image testimonial carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a website.

I used testimonial carousel , I use this [tutorial](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/carousel-with-face-indicators)

```
                <div class="col-md-12" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="quote-carousel">
                        <!-- Bottom Carousel Indicators -->
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><img class="img-responsive " src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brad_frost/128.jpg" alt="">
                            </li>
                            <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="1"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/rssems/128.jpg" alt="">
                            </li>
                            <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="2"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adellecharles/128.jpg" alt="">
                            </li>
                        </ol>
```

But i have a problem, images in carousel are changing position in mobile screen. I tried to clear the image class: `img-responsive` , but no effect.
How to make the images unresponsive??

Answer (score 0):

In the given tutorial link, the thumbnails are overlapping the content area, because its set with `position: absolute;` It should be `position: relative;` in media query
Here is reference class:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .carousel-indicators {
   position: relative;
   bottom: 10px;
   left: 50%;
   z-index: 15;
   width: 60%;
   padding-left: 0;
   margin-left: -30%;
   text-align: center;
   list-style: none;
 }
}
```

In the given tutorial there is fixed width & height to #quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li and #quote-carousel .carousel-indicators .active which need to be changed in different screen views

Try this :

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li {
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
  }
  #quote-carousel .carousel-indicators .active {
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
  }
}
```

Comment: i have changed with code what you discribed, but the thubnails still responsive.

Comment: @hahardyan, edited my answer to give you more understanding